# reusing postgresql connection pool in nodejs

Tags: node.js, postgresql, async-await

I have the following postgresql connection file in nodejs:

```
// postgresql.js

"use strict";

const { Pool } = require('pg');

module.exports = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const pool = new Pool({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 5432,
    user: 'postgres',
    password: 'postgres',
    database: 'postgres',
    connectionTimeoutMillis: 0,
    idleTimeoutMillis: 0,
    min: 10,
    max: 20,
  });

  resolve({ pool });
});
```

I'm using a promise because later on, I will start using [Google Cloud Secret Manager](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager). The secrets are fetched asynchronous so the database connection cannot be established when the server starts.

In my controller files, I'm using it like this:

```
// apicontroller.js

"use strict";

const postgresql = require('./postgresql');

app.get('/api/test', async (req, res, next) => {
// resolve the postgresql promise
const { pool } = await postgresql;

// resolve the pool.connect() promise
const client = await pool.connect();

// use the client object here
// eg. await client.query(...)
});
```

The problem is not that it doesn't work, instead, it works like a charm! But I'm questioning myself: am I reusing the connection pool, or am I creating a new connection (pool) every time this route is requested?

Is this the correct way to reuse a database connection only once?

Edit: I included only relevant code parts.

Answer (score 5):

As it is explained in the documentation of [node-postgres](https://node-postgres.com/features/pooling), I would use `pool.query` rather than using (handling) the `client`.

> **Single query,**
> If you don't need a transaction or you just need to run a single query, the pool has a convenience method to run a query on any available client in the pool. This is the preferred way to query with node-postgres if you can as it removes the risk of leaking a client.

So my code would be like;

**postgresql.js**

```
let mainPool = null;

function createPool(){
  const pool = new Pool({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 5432,
    user: 'postgres',
    password: 'postgres',
    database: 'postgres',
    connectionTimeoutMillis: 0,
    idleTimeoutMillis: 0,
    min: 10,
    max: 20,
  });
  return pool;
}

function getPool(){
  if(!mainPool){
    mainPool = createPool();
  }
  return mailPool;
}

export default { getPool };
```

**controller.js**

```
const { getPool } = require('./postgresql');

app.get('/api/test', async (req, res, next) => {
  getPool().query('SELECT * FROM users', [], (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
       return res.status(500).send(err);
    }
    return res.status(500).send(res);
  });
});
```

Comment: This neither answers the question nor does it work in the OP's scenario. It doesn't matter how the use the pool (with single queries or a managed client), the problem is about how to asynchronously acquire the pool.

Comment: @Bergi Please read the question first! `Is this the correct way to reuse a database connection only once?` As you can see in the OP's question. And that sample in the question has a solution for async call.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question (which could be improved, I admit). It's about reusing the pool correctly, not about making a query only once per request.

Comment: @Bergi I think you misunderstood my answer. I gave an answer which helps OP to reuse the pool. Could you tell me what is wrong with the answer? Isn't possible to reuse the pool with the functinality in my answer then?

Comment: Maybe I got distracted by the irrelevant quote about single-query use of the pool at the top. If you refer to the singleton pattern in `getPool`, yes that might be an answer that I had overlooked. And still `createPool` should be returning a promise as it does in the OP's code.

Comment: This answer should be marked as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are reusing the same pool object that is stored as the result of the exported promise. There is only one, there's no code that would create a second instance, the module is evaluated only once no matter how often you `require` it.

There is however a small problem with error handling - if the database pool cannot be created (e.g. the secrets fail to load), you need to handle this somewhere (and probably crash the application) instead of waiting for an `unhandledrejection` event.

While your code is fine, consider the alternative approach of not starting the http server until the pool (and its connection details) are acquired, then passing the pool (not a promise for it) to all the routes. This also ensures that the http server isn't started at all if its dependencies fail to initialise.

Comment: How can I delay the start of the server and pass the pool object to all controllers? Do I use app.set for that? Or wrap all controllers in a parent function and pass the pool object as a parameter? Edit: thank you for your answer btw!

Comment: @yesterday Yes, either of those, and then move the `createServer` call inside the `postgresql.then(…)` callback.

Comment: The problem is: I have multiple promises (also for a redis connection). Should It be an option to use Promise.all() and put the create server in the “then” part of this?

Comment: @yesterday Yes, exactly, `Promise.all` is perfect for that.